# Github Action for running Powershell scripts on remote Windows server

Tags: github-actions

I've seen a lot of github actions for connecting to Linux servers via SSH like https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action
However, I'm looking for a github Action for moving files from github to a remote windows server.

Does anyone know of a github action that exists for doing this?

Comment: Windows 10 and Server 2019 [support running an SSH server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse), which should work in the same way as the Linux server does.

Comment: Also how remote are you talking? Can you get to the remote machine via [UNC paths](https://superuser.com/a/120264/324301)?  Really you should figure out how to do it outside on your local machine, then write up your solution in an Actions workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Look at these solutions:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01, Server02 -FilePath c:\Scripts\DiskCollect.ps1
```

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/blob/main/reference/docs-conceptual/learn/remoting/Running-Remote-Commands.md#run-a-script

And as noted in the comments, you can set up OpenSSH server on a remote host